# android.view.InflateException username in toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, layout-inflater

I want to appear the username in the toolbar, in right corner.

After I submit a login dialog, try change, the username, but gave error.

```
2021-10-11 12:16:47.528 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32 in hu.fherp.application:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #32 in hu.fherp.application:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
2021-10-11 12:16:47.528 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err: Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32 in hu.fherp.application:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
2021-10-11 12:16:47.530 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2021-10-11 12:16:47.530 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.531 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.531 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.531 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.531 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.532 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.532 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.532 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.532 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.533 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.533 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.533 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.533 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at hu.fherp.application.WebserviceHelper.loginSuccesfull(WebserviceHelper.kt:293)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.533 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at hu.fherp.application.WebserviceHelper.getJSONObjectWebservice(WebserviceHelper.kt:169)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.534 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at hu.fherp.application.MainActivity.putCustomerOpenBaskets(MainActivity.kt:147)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.534 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at hu.fherp.application.MainActivity.dashboardBindings(MainActivity.kt:78)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.534 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at hu.fherp.application.MainActivity.applyTexts(MainActivity.kt:206)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.535 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at hu.fherp.application.DialogLogin.onCreateDialog$lambda-1(DialogLogin.kt:49)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.535 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at hu.fherp.application.DialogLogin.lambda$4zIzu4sTTPHlZVOdwhB12WdRF9Q(Unknown Source:0)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.535 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at hu.fherp.application.-$$Lambda$DialogLogin$4zIzu4sTTPHlZVOdwhB12WdRF9Q.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.535 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.536 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.536 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.536 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.536 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.537 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.537 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1139)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.538 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0300dd a=-1}
2021-10-11 12:16:47.539 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:997)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.539 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:981)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.540 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5954)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.540 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:715)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.540 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:711)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.540 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:237)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.541 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:     at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:233)
2021-10-11 12:16:47.541 22775-22775/hu.fherp.application W/System.err:  ... 27 more
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_grey_bg"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"

            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_appname_container"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
                android:layout_width="10pt"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textAppName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:textSize="22dp"
                    android:text=""

                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_item_container"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textUserName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:text="Username"

                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
.....
```

WebserviceHelper.kt

```
class WebserviceHelper {
 private lateinit var activityContext: Context
....
  fun getJSONArrayWebservice(context: Context, wsName: String, activityContext: AppCompatActivity, supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager): JSONArray {
        this.activityContext = context
   ...
  }

 private fun loginSuccesfull () {

        val mContext: Context = this.activityContext.applicationContext

        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
   
        val layout: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null)
        val textView = layout.findViewById<View>(R.id.textUserName) as TextView
        textView.text = this.username

        //val activity: AppCompatActivity = (AppCompatActivity) this.activityContext
        //val textUserName: TextView =  activity.findViewById(R.id.textUserName)
        //textUserName.text = this.username
    }
```

I read many topic from this, but doesn't helpd.  For example, "change the style". I changed, but the exception doesn't disappear.

stlye.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CheckBoxGreyGreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/dark_grey</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/box_green</item>
    </style>
    <style name="RadioButtonGreyGreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/dark_grey</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/box_green</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Thank you any ideas.

**Solution**:

```
  val textUserName: TextView =  this.appCompatActivity.findViewById(R.id.textUserName)
        textUserName.text = this.username
```

Comment: Do not use `applicationContext` to inflate layouts; it does not have your theme set on it. Use the `Activity` instead. (I'm not sure that that's going to do what you think it will, though. The `activity_main` instance you create there has no relation to any `MainActivity` instance that might already be running.)

Comment: I've tried to use Ativity before I send this topic. Look my code, the // removed part.  But didn't work because "unrecognise function findViewById"

But try again and work now.  I am very grateful. Thanks. Please write as a regular reply and I will tick. 
        val textUserName: TextView =  this.appCompatActivity.findViewById(R.id.textUserName)
        textUserName.text = this.username

Comment: Oh, it's cool. :-) Nothing major. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it figured out. Cheers!